# using different css for different page in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I am new  to WordPress I want to use a a different CSS for my landing page named 'as'. I have a default style sheet style.css , jquery-bxslider.css and responsive.css.
I don't want to use style .css whereas I want to use other two to be applied on my particular page.

**images:

Directory structure:**
 [image]

**WP header:**
[image]

**WP- css:**

[image]

Comment: Please, post `code` instead of a snapshot of code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **wp_enqueue_style()** to add stylesheets to your template.

```
function add_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_register_style( 'bxslider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'jquery.bxslider.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . 'responsive.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style('style'); // enqueue style.css everywhere

    ## if( ! is_page_template('landingpage.php') ) // enqueue style.css everywhere except if the page template is landingpage.php
    ##    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    ## if( ! is_page(ID) ) // enqueue style.css everywhere except page id = ID
    ##    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    ## if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) // enqueue style.css in homepage only
    ##    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    wp_enqueue_style('bxslider');
    wp_enqueue_setyle('responsive');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheets' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the current page ID and setting the respective css

For E.g in header

```
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
if($page_id==1)
    //include the respective css
elseif($page_id==2)
    //include the respective css
elseif($page_id==3)
    //include the respective css
```